# CSS Animation visible too soon

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I am doing a circle animation on CSS, problem I have is the fact that my "circle" is visible outside of the green box at the start of the animation (mostly visible on Google Chrome).
It's really quick and visible only sometimes.
Is it possible to delay the visibility of the white circle so it doesn't show outside?
Also the circle icon is a FontAwesome, so not visible here unfortunately..

```css
.meal section {
    margin-left: 1rem;
    margin-right: 1rem;
}
.meal section h2 {
    font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-size: 100%;
    margin-top: 0.5rem;
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}
.meal hr {
    height: 0.2rem;
    width: 2.6rem;
    border: none;
    background-color: #99E2D0;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
.meal div {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #0000002e;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    height: 4rem;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 1rem;
    padding-top: 1rem;
    animation: fadeIn 0.7s ease-in both, top 0.5s linear;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.meal div:nth-of-type(1) {
    animation-delay: 0.2s;
}
.meal div:nth-of-type(2) {
    animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
.meal div:nth-of-type(3) {
    animation-delay: 0.8s;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {
        top: 3rem;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
        top: 0rem;
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
.meal__price {
    position: absolute;
    top: 2rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    left: 85%; 
}
.price {
    position: absolute;
    right: 2rem;
    top: 1rem;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.meal h3, .meal__description {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.meal h3 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 70%;
}
.meal__description {
    position: absolute;
    top: 2rem;
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 70%;
}
.meal span {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #99E2D0;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    bottom: 0rem;
    width: 0%;
    justify-content: center;
    border-top-right-radius: 0.9rem;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0.9rem;
    left: 100%;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.375rem;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
.fa-check-circle {
    visibility: hidden;
}
.meal div:hover span {
    left: 80%;
    visibility: visible;
    width: 20%;
}
.meal div:hover .fa-check-circle {
    visibility: visible;
}
.meal div:hover .meal__price {
    left: 65%;
}
.meal div:hover .meal__description {
    width: 50%;
}
.meal div:hover i {
    animation: rotation 0.4s linear 0.1s;
}

@keyframes rotation {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
.meal div:hover .meal__price {
        animation: move-animation 0.2s linear forwards;
    }

@keyframes move-animation {
    from {
        left: 85%;
    }
    to {
        left: 70%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="meal">
                <section>
                    <h2>ENTRÉES</h2><hr>
                    <div>
                        <h3>Tartare de poulpe acidulé</h3>
                        <p class="meal__description">Aux zests d'orange</p>
                        <p class="meal__price">25€</p>
                        <span>
                            <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h3>Velouté de légumes d'antan</h3>
                        <p class="meal__description">Carotte, panais, topinambour</p>
                        <p class="meal__price">35€</p>
                        <span>
                            <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h3>Soupe à l'oignon</h3>
                        <p class="meal__description">Revisitée</p>
                        <p class="meal__price">20€</p>
                        <span>
                            <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </section>
                <section>
                    <h2>PLATS</h2><hr>
                    <div>
                        <h3>Coquilles Saint-Jacques</h3>
                        <p class="meal__description">Accompagnées d'une purée de panais</p>
                        <p class="meal__price">40€</p>
                        <span>
                            <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h3>Magret de canard</h3>
                        <p class="meal__description">Et parmentier de pommes de terre</p>
                        <p class="meal__price">35€</p>
                        <span>
                            <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h3>Pigeonneau d’Ille-et-Vilaine</h3>
                        <p class="meal__description">Sur son lit de gnocchis aux légumes</p>
                        <p class="meal__price">44€</p>
                        <span>
                            <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </section>
                <section>
                    <h2>DESSERTS</h2><hr>
                    <div>
                        <h3>Pétales de violettes glacés</h3>
                        <p class="meal__description">Et purée de noisettes</p>
                        <p class="meal__price">18€</p>
                        <span>
                            <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h3>Fondant au chocolat</h3>
                        <p class="meal__description">Revisité</p>
                        <p class="meal__price">22€</p>
                        <span>
                            <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h3>Millefeuille croustillant</h3>
                        <p class="meal__description">Myrtilles et pâte d’amande</p>
                        <p class="meal__price">23€</p>
                        <span>
                            <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
            <div class="commander">
                <button class="btn" type="button" href="#restaurants">Commander</button>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove this rule:

```
.meal div:hover .fa-check-circle {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Then edit the `rotation` animation and add `visibility: visible`:

```
@keyframes rotation {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    visibility: visible; /* Add this */
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

Finally adjust the `rotation` animation delay as needed and set [`animation-fill-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode) to `forwards`:

```
.meal div:hover i {
  animation: rotation 0.4s linear 0.15s forwards;
}
```

Here is a working example. `.fa-check-circle` is set as a rectangle just for demo.

```css
.meal section {
  margin-left: 1rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.meal section h2 {
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 100%;
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.meal hr {
  height: 0.2rem;
  width: 2.6rem;
  border: none;
  background-color: #99e2d0;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.meal div {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #0000002e;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  height: 4rem;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  animation: fadeIn 0.7s ease-in both, top 0.5s linear;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.meal div:nth-of-type(1) {
  animation-delay: 0.2s;
}

.meal div:nth-of-type(2) {
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}

.meal div:nth-of-type(3) {
  animation-delay: 0.8s;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    top: 3rem;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    top: 0rem;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.meal__price {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  left: 85%;
}

.price {
  position: absolute;
  right: 2rem;
  top: 1rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.meal h3,
.meal__description {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.meal h3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 70%;
}

.meal__description {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2rem;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 70%;
}

.meal span {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #99e2d0;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  bottom: 0rem;
  width: 0%;
  justify-content: center;
  border-top-right-radius: 0.9rem;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0.9rem;
  left: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.375rem;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.fa-check-circle {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.meal div:hover span {
  left: 80%;
  visibility: visible;
  width: 20%;
}

.meal div:hover .fa-check-circle {
  /* visibility: visible; */
}

.meal div:hover .meal__price {
  left: 65%;
}

.meal div:hover .meal__description {
  width: 50%;
}

.meal div:hover i {
  animation: rotation 0.4s linear 0.15s forwards;
}

@keyframes show-circle {
  100% {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}

@keyframes rotation {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    visibility: visible;
    /* Add this */
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.meal div:hover .meal__price {
  animation: move-animation 0.2s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes move-animation {
  from {
    left: 85%;
  }
  to {
    left: 70%;
  }
}

.fa-check-circle {
  width: 30px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="meal">
  <section>
    <h2>ENTRÉES</h2>
    <hr />
    <div>
      <h3>Tartare de poulpe acidulé</h3>
      <p class="meal__description">Aux zests d'orange</p>
      <p class="meal__price">25€</p>
      <span>
            <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
          </span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>Velouté de légumes d'antan</h3>
      <p class="meal__description">Carotte, panais, topinambour</p>
      <p class="meal__price">35€</p>
      <span>
            <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
          </span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>Soupe à l'oignon</h3>
      <p class="meal__description">Revisitée</p>
      <p class="meal__price">20€</p>
      <span>
            <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
          </span>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h2>PLATS</h2>
    <hr />
    <div>
      <h3>Coquilles Saint-Jacques</h3>
      <p class="meal__description">Accompagnées d'une purée de panais</p>
      <p class="meal__price">40€</p>
      <span>
            <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
          </span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>Magret de canard</h3>
      <p class="meal__description">Et parmentier de pommes de terre</p>
      <p class="meal__price">35€</p>
      <span>
            <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
          </span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>Pigeonneau d’Ille-et-Vilaine</h3>
      <p class="meal__description">Sur son lit de gnocchis aux légumes</p>
      <p class="meal__price">44€</p>
      <span>
            <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
          </span>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h2>DESSERTS</h2>
    <hr />
    <div>
      <h3>Pétales de violettes glacés</h3>
      <p class="meal__description">Et purée de noisettes</p>
      <p class="meal__price">18€</p>
      <span>
            <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
          </span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>Fondant au chocolat</h3>
      <p class="meal__description">Revisité</p>
      <p class="meal__price">22€</p>
      <span>
            <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
          </span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>Millefeuille croustillant</h3>
      <p class="meal__description">Myrtilles et pâte d’amande</p>
      <p class="meal__price">23€</p>
      <span>
            <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
          </span>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
<div class="commander">
  <button class="btn" type="button" href="#restaurants">Commander</button>
</div>
```